# Expressing that a food is naturally hot

Tags: vocabulary, adjectives

When you want to say that a food, for instance, is naturally hot, what do you call it?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I presume you mean like chilli, not like boiling water. You'd actually say 'hot' but then you'd have to qualify it… so you end up saying 'spicy' instead.

Comment: What do you mean by "naturally hot"?

Answer (score 5):

You can use 'hot' to refer to food that is at a high temperature or that is 'spicy' in taste. It confuses us native english speakers all the time in conversations!

For example - both of these sound very standard:

> 1. The nachos just came out of the oven and are very hot.
> 2. The nachos are topped with jalapeños and are very hot.

---

I recommend using 'spicy' to refer to food that is naturally 'hot' in flavor to avoid confusion.

Comment: We often disambiguate with phrases like: "No, it's not "hot-hot" it's "spicy-hot"

Comment: There also tends to be a subtle stress on the word when mentioning temperature heat, which is given more as a 'danger' warning than the more casual warning that something is spicy - presumably because the former tends to cause injury while the latter usually only causes discomfort (other than in extreme cases, which would normally be mentioned)... Although I mention this more for reference/interest than as a consistent rule.

Comment: Note to learners - As @jim notes _hot_ can be reliably (if informally) used to modify _hot_ to indicate that the temperature is being described (e.g. _hot-hot fried chicken_).  Many other words normally associated with temperature will not unambiguously perform the same function.  For example _"smoking hot," "blazing hot," "fiery hot," "flaming hot,"_ and _"burning hot"_ all **could** be used to describe spiciness.  _"Piping hot,"_ however, refers exclusively to temperature. (AmE)

Comment: **3.** `The nachos are an exciting new product and are very hot.`   (The nachos are selling quickly.)  **4.** `The nachos have their serial numbers ground off and are very hot.`  (The nachos are stolen property.) **5.** `The nachos are wearing skimpy bikinis and are very hot.` (The nachos are sexually appealing.)

Comment: **5.** I find the nachos rather attractive, wow they look hot in those skimpy ...ermmm… plates... ;)

Comment: Bahaha... all great usages of hot :D