# What do you call food that is hot in temperature?

Tags: word-usage

For example, do you say "hot soup"?
I ask this because the word "hot" is ambiguous. It could mean "spicy."
If "hot soup" is ambiguous, what do you call it?
The shorter, the better.

Comment: You can't tell from only *hot*. Context (which you didn't give) should tell you which one it means. You could plug in a number of synonyms for *hot*.

Comment: Native speakers use _spicy hot_ to refer to food which is flavored with peppers, and _hot_ to refer to food with a high temperature. If it should be necessary to make the distinction in conversation, NAmE speakers will use _spicy hot_ for pepper-flavored food, and _fire hot_ to refer to high-temperature food. For instance, at Tempo Doeloe in Amsterdam, over a plate of rijsttafel, we might gasp: _**"Whew, that's hot - spicy hot, not fire hot!"**_

Comment: Also related: [Meaning of _hot and spicy_](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/54529/what-could-hot-and-spicy-mean)

Comment: I personally don't ever say "fire hot" but either "hot hot"  or "temperatures-wise hot"  when wanting to clarify that I mean a food is hot in temperature. This goes for all native speakers of American English that I know.

Answer (score 0):

The more common meaning and the first definition of ***[hot](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/hot)*** you'll find in dictionaries is related to temperature. It is generally and in my experience easily  understood by context if hot is used to mean spicy. So if you are being served something which is both hot and spicy, both terms are used.

Hot:

***having a high temperature:***

> - *a hot, sunny day
>     hot **a hot drink/meal**
>     It's too hot in here, can we turn down the heating?
>     Bake the cake in a hot oven, about 220°C, for 30 minutes.
>     The food was piping hot (= very hot).*

(Cambridge Dictionary)